# Spring Integration File Polling complex structure - subdirectories

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am currently using [this project](https://github.com/iainporter/spring-file-poller) as an attempt to listen and poll files from a FS structure, start Spring Batch jobs from them and write'em back to a different folder.

Unfortunately, as I can guess, it can only define one single folder for each type of channel (read, out, fail and processed). I would like to define a parent folder for each channel and a few children folders to be automatically created and have a scanner on.

E.g:

```
entrada:
    path: /opt/app/inbound/
    informantes:
        - Bradesco
        - Itau
        - Caixa
        - Banco do Brasil
        - Santander
```

Do you guys have any hint on if and how can this be achieved?

I've seen this link [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html), but I couldn't figure it out how to adapt it to this solution.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Best regards,
Enrico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see a `RecursiveDirectoryScanner` there in Spring Integration?

```
 * The {@link DefaultDirectoryScanner} extension which walks through the directory tree
 * using {@link Files#walk(Path, int, FileVisitOption...)}.
 * <p>
 * By default this class visits all levels of the file tree without any {@link FileVisitOption}s.
```

What files to accept or not you can determine by particular `filter`, e.g. `RegexPatternFileListFilter`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I've gone through this section and didn't pay the required attention. Still I don't think I understand how to correctly adapt my bean to use the proper scanner.

Comment: The `scanner` is a `FileReadingMessageSource` ctor arg

Comment: Oh yea. I could've explained it better... I found the `.setScanner()` method, I just didn't get the correct way to declare and pass a RecursiveDirectoryScanner to it.So far I was able to find 0 articles about this matter.

Comment: Did you get it now? Do we have anything else to discuss here?

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get it. Would you care to please share a piece of code on how to implement it properly?

Comment: Well, I’m still not sure what you need from us at all. I just gave you a hint which may help you to implement your task. But its description is a bit unclear, at least for me. Any here is a test-case for this `RecursiveDirectoryScanner`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file/RecursiveDirectoryScannerTests.java